# Issue in insert using date with timestamp table- Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I have a pl/sql block to insert data to a table 'report_2019' on the basis of a created timestamp table -dates_2019.

```
TS_RANGE_BEGIN      |TS_RANGE_END
2019-01-01 17:00:00 |2019-01-02 17:00:00
2019-01-02 17:00:00 |2019-01-03 17:00:00
2019-01-03 17:00:00 |2019-01-04 17:00:00
2019-01-04 17:00:00 |2019-01-07 17:00:00
2019-01-07 17:00:00 |2019-01-08 17:00:00
2019-01-08 17:00:00 |2019-01-09 17:00:00
```

The idea is to select and insert for each entry in dates_2019 one at a time in order to avoid temp tablespace issues.
Could you please help fix this?

```
declare

ts_range_begin timestamp;
ts_range_end timestamp;

begin

select ts_range_end into ts_range_end from dates_2019;
select ts_range_begin into ts_range_begin from dates_2019;

FOR i IN (select ts_range_begin,ts_range_end from dates_2019) LOOP

insert into report_2019(start_time,end_time,ab,app_name,status,sub_count,category,last_modified_timestamp)
with T as (
select id,start_time,end_time,ab,app_name,status,trunc(last_modified_timestamp),
     row_number() over(partition by id, ab order by p_message_id desc, message_id desc) lastest_status_order_id
          ,p_message_id
         ,LAST_MODIFIED_TIMESTAMP,reporting_purpose
from (
    select
     id,
     ab 
     , app_name,
 status
    ,p.message_id p_message_id
       ,s.message_id
    ,s.LAST_MODIFIED_TIMESTAMP, reporting_purpose
    from table_a s, table_b d, table_c k, table_d t,
        table_e p
    where s.LAST_MODIFIED_TIMESTAMP > ts_range_begin
and s.LAST_MODIFIED_TIMESTAMP <= ts_range_end
    and .....
  ) a
)
select * from (
 select start_time,end_time,ab, app_name, status, count(*) subtotal, 
'Reporting' as v_category,trunc(last_modified_timestamp)
 from T  where lastest_status_order_id = 1
 and LAST_MODIFIED_TIMESTAMP <= ts_range_end
 group by start_time,end_time,ab,app_name,status,trunc(last_modified_timestamp))a order by ab, app_name;


--i= i+1;
ts_range_begin  := NULL ;
ts_range_end  := NULL ;

ts_range_begin  := i.ts_range_begin ;
ts_range_end  := i.ts_range_end;

end loop;
commit;
end;
```

[Error Code: 6550, SQL State: 65000]  ORA-06550: line 66, column 4:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '+'

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried removing the `i = i+1`; ?

Comment: ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at line 8 ...this is the error if I remove i = i+1;

Comment: I have edited the code to handle ORA-01422 error.However am not quite sure if it will be able to resolve the space errors as it executes.

Comment: So now do you have a program logic issue or a performance tuning issue?

Comment: its a performance tuning issue.

Comment: try moving the commit inside the loop

Comment: What gives you the impression that slow-by-slow processing (1 at a time) will resolve your temp space issue and as for performance tuning your solution is the cause of poor performance. Suppose you inner insert...select returns 1000 rows for each row in dates_ table, that a mesly 365K rows. If your system cannot handle that it is way, way under resourced. If you stay with the slow-by-slow process then DO NOT put the commit inside the loop. Contrary to popular belief that will most likely require **more resources** not less to maintain MVCC. Google "ORA-1555: snapshot too old"